# calculating correlations between columns with different lengths in R

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I have a data frame with 14 columns and I want to calculate the correlations between these columns. However, there are NA's in some of the columns. Initially, I used na.omit(a) to remove the NA from the data frame and then used cor to calculate the correlations, but doing na.omit removed most of my observations due to 5 columns which are mostly NA's.

Currently, I am trying to use a For Loop to go through individually select a column,use na.omit,calculate the correlations, and put the value in a array. I will repeat this process for all the variables. Below is a sample of the data and a sample of my code.

```
head(selected_data)

final initial qualitative quantitative Revenue
 NA     1        2           11           2 
  1    NA        4           3           NA 
 NA    NA        8           NA          NA 
 8     7         9           6            3

a=na.omit(selected_data$final)
b=na.omit(selected_data$initial)
c=na.omit(selected_data$qualitative)
d=na.omit(selected_data$quantitative)
e=na.omit(selected_data$Revenue)


      col_name =c('a', 'b' ,'c', 'd', 'e')
   i="a"
   j="a"
   for (i in col_name) {
       for (j in col_name) {
          Rating_array<-cor(i,j)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, loop isn't working. I am new to R and I am open to a better approach. I would appreciate for any help that is provided.

Comment: Check out `?cor`  this will give you a list of how you can handle NAs.  You have a number of options all specified with the use parameter.  You should select the option that best fits what you want to do.

Comment: For example `cor(selected_data, use = "everything")`

Comment: I used cor(selected_data, use = "everything") and it provided everything as NA. I will go through the list that ?cor provided and test it out.

Comment: I got the answer! I used 'cor(selected_data, use="complete.obs")'. Thanks Ian!